# PHP Returning incorrect records from MYSQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

Have the following code..  I have set up a password reset system for my website and it has suddenly broken.  I was changing the form sending data method from standard HTML/PHP to using AJAX .post() method but dont think that has anything to do with the results I am seeing.

**Issue:** when the $timeSQL query runs it returns 0 num_rows(), yet when I run this in phpmyadmin I get the expected results.  I am not using a count(*) in my SQL statement as I saw many of these answers were referencing so am not sure what is the problem..

Each attempt I am always getting this code to fire:

```
echo "<script> 
       alert('It has been longer than 1 hour since you last requested to reset your password and your code has expired.  Please request to reset it again on the login page by clicking Forgot Password link at the bottom of the login page.');
       window.location='login.php';
     </script>";
```

Here is pastebin with same code: http://pastebin.com/S5Yi9MAQ

**Thanks for all help**

```
<?php

include('config.php');

ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

$token = $_GET["token"];

if (isset($_POST['rpTempCode'])){
    //Check to see if more than 10 mins has elapsed since password reset request
    $timeSQL = "SELECT codeExpireDate, sysdate(), tempCode FROM users WHERE token = '".$token."' AND codeExpireDate > sysdate()";
    $timeResult = mysqli_query($db,$timeSQL);


    $count = mysqli_num_rows($timeResult);
    echo "<script>alert('count: ".$count."');</script>";


    if (mysqli_num_rows($timeResult) > 0){
        $timeRow = $timeResult->fetch_assoc();

        $tempCodeFromDB = $timeRow["tempCode"];

        $newPassword = mysqli_escape_string($db, $_POST["rpNewPassword"]);
        $tempCode = mysqli_escape_string($db, $_POST["rpTempCode"]);

        if ($tempCode == $tempCodeFromDB){
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET password = '".$newPassword."', locked = 0 WHERE token = '".$token."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            if ($result == FALSE){
                //add error handling here..
                echo "Error updating new password in DB..";
            } else {
                //good
                echo "<script> alert('Password updated! You can now login.'); window.location='login.php'; </script>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<script> alert('Incorrect code entered, please try again.'); </script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script> alert('It has been longer than 1 hour since you last      requested to reset your password and your code has expired.  Please request to reset it again on the login page by clicking Forgot Password link at the bottom of the login page.');
                       window.location='login.php';
            </script>";
    }
}
```

**Update:**
So far I have identified that there is an issue when trying to use PHP's $result->num_rows > 0 with jQuery .post() method.  It will return 0 records returned count each time.  Tried to return all the data and then do the count on the receiving JS/jQuery end and use something like:

```
var rowCount = $('#countMe').length;
```

to count all the div's that come back thinking that would work but it also failed..

Comment: [Escape](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) $token or use [parameterised query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thanks, added that in. @Sheepy